# How to write a TypeScript NPM package with JSX property suggestion/autocompletion for intellisense

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, styled-components

I created a mini UI library and published it to NPM registry. My library is written with strongly typed styled-components (TypeScript) and can be imported in React applications. It works fine when I install it using `npm install charge-ui` and works well with NextJs.

Example:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
// my library
import { Text, CallToActionButton } from "charge-ui";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CallToActionButton cursorPointer> Hire me </CallToActionButton> <br />
      <Text m={1}> Hello </Text>
      <Text m={1} className='title' fontSize='3rem'> Hello </Text>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The problem is my `CallToActionButton` component has the following type:

```
export type CallToActionType = {
  cursorPointer?: boolean;
  width?: string;
};

export const CallToActionButton = styled.button<CallToActionType>`
    //some css code
`;
```

but VS Code doesn't seem to detect its props. There is no suggestion/autocompletion showing up. If you take a look at [my repo](https://github.com/EricEchemane/Charge-UI), the package is inside /lib folder and it has corresponding `*.d.ts` files. This also applies to other components.

[image]

Did I miss something here? Do you have any recommendation on how to autocomplete in VS Code with my library?

Comment: Here is the [link](https://github.com/EricEchemane/Charge-UI/blob/main/package.json) to my package.json

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the solution. Just include `typescript` in dependencies and not in devDependencies. Mine was in the devDependencies

package.json should be something like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
},
```